# Move Group Interface C++

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying the first lot of tutorials from the moveit website and I am having trouble with the move group interface.
Here is my cpp file:

```
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h>

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm_t");
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::NodeHandle node;
ros::Publisher display_publisher = node.advertise<moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory>("/move_group/display_planned_path", 1, true);
moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory display_trajectory;

ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", group.getPlanningFrame().c_str());
ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", group.getEndEffectorLink().c_str());

geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1;
target_pose1.orientation.w = 1.0;
target_pose1.position.x = 0.28;
target_pose1.position.y = -0.7;
target_pose1.position.z = 1.0;
group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;
bool success = group.plan(my_plan);

ROS_INFO("Visualizing plan 1 (pose goal) %s",success?"":"FAILED");
/* Sleep to give Rviz time to visualize the plan. */
sleep(5.0);

return 0;
}
```

When I try to catkin_make, It come up with the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/moveit_trial.dir/src/nod_plan.cpp.o: In function `main':
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::getPlanningFrame() const'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x2a1): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::getEndEffectorLink() const'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::setPoseTarget(geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x3b7): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::plan(moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_trial.dir/src/nod_plan.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x7f7): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::MoveGroup(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> const&, ros::Duration const&)'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x82c): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::~MoveGroup()'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x848): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface::PlanningSceneInterface()'
nod_plan.cpp:(.text+0x84d): undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface::~PlanningSceneInterface()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/thibault/reem-sim_ws/devel/lib/moveit_trial/moveit_trial] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit_trial/CMakeFiles/moveit_trial.dir/all] Error 2
```

I have tried modifying my CmakeLists and package.xml but it still comes up with the same error. Can anyone help with this issue please.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242141/move-group-interface-c++/) by [Thibault_Rouillard](https://answers.ros.org/users/24338/thibault_rouillard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2017-12-26**:
Hey, facing the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What ros distribution do you have? The moveit is not released for kinetic yet.

In any case, as I can see the compiler doesn't recognise the member functions of the classes of MoveIt, so be sure you have installed and linked everything correctly.

If there's an undefined reference error, usually it's because the .o file (which gets created from the .cpp file) doesn't exist and your compiler/build system is not able to link it.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thibault_Rouillard](https://answers.ros.org/users/24338/thibault_rouillard/) on 2016-08-23**:
Thanks for that. I am using ROS hydro at the moment. I haven't got it to work yet

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-24**:
are you sure you have installed everything correctly? What page's instructions did you follow for the installation?

**Comment by [Thibault_Rouillard](https://answers.ros.org/users/24338/thibault_rouillard/) on 2016-08-31**:
sorry for the late response, I was trying to build the package myself using the code from the moveit tutorial and the actual moveit website.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-31**:
Be sure that you have installed moveit correctly in your system. The error is coming from there.

**Comment by [Thibault_Rouillard](https://answers.ros.org/users/24338/thibault_rouillard/) on 2016-08-31**:
alright thank you.